# What kind of programs can gdb be used to debug?

Tags: gdb, debugging

Can GDB be used to debug programs in languages other than C or C++, like Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDB can debug a variety of file formats, but it doesn't support scripted languages (Perl, PHP, Python, etc) <del>nor languages that run over a VM (Java, C#, etc)</del>. Nowadays it can even debug Java. It was made to debug native binaries like ELF, Mach-O, etc.

You can read the complete list of supported file formats on the official GDB documentation. [Here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Supported-Languages.html#Supported-Languages)!

Comment: Can you list a few languages that can generate native binaries? I can only think of c/c++ ...

Comment: Pascal, ObjC, Ada, Fortran, Assembly, etc.